# XSLT Divide pargraphs into two column table

Tags: xslt

I have an unknown number of paragraphs that I would like to format into a two column table. So, if I have an even number of paragraphs, I'd like to go from

```
<doc>
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
<p>Paragraph 3</p>
<p>Paragraph 4</p>
</doc>
```

to

```
<table>
  <row>
    <entry>
      <p>Paragraph 1</p>
      <p>Paragraph 2</p>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <p>Paragraph 3</p>
      <p>Paragraph 4</p>
    </entry>
  </row>
</table>
```

If I have an odd number of paragraphs, I would like to split it with one more in the first column (7 paras = 4/3, 11 paras = 6/5, etc).

I'm having trouble figuring out how to iterate over the paragraphs and put them in the proper column. I need to start/end the table no matter what, the only real challenge is deciding when to end column 1 and start column 2.  I think I need to store the number of paragraphs before I start and then move to column 2 when I reach the right paragraph number, but I'm having trouble doing this.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can get a count of the number of `p` elements you want in the first entry:

```
 <xsl:variable name="count" select="ceiling(count(p) div 2)" />
```

Then you can select the `p` elements that occur in position 1 and position of `count` + 1, as these represent the first element in each `entry`

```
<xsl:for-each select="p[position() = 1 or position() = $count + 1]">
```

Then you can select the `p` tags for each entry like so:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="self::p|following::p[position() &lt; $count]" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="doc">
        <table>
          <row>
            <xsl:variable name="count" select="ceiling(count(p) div 2)" />
            <xsl:value-of select="$count" />
            <xsl:for-each select="p[position() = 1 or position() = $count + 1]">
                <entry>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="self::p|following::p[position() &lt; $count]" />
                </entry>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </row>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility to achieve this is the following XSLT snippet. It divides between counts of `position() < ((last() of element p)/2+1)` and those, that are not in that nodeset. The rest is simply copied and the surrounding elements are created (confirming to best practice) in the `doc` template.

```
<xsl:template match="/doc">
    <xsl:element name="table">
        <xsl:element name="row">
            <xsl:element name="entry">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="p[position() &lt; (last() div 2)+1]" />
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="entry">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="p[not(position() &lt; (last() div 2)+1)]" />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:template>
```